# Can we implement After Throwing Advice with CDI?

Tags: cdi, aop

I am working in a Java web application. I need to handle RuntimeException using After Throwing Advice but my application is not using AspectJ/Spring AOP. Is it possible to implement similar thing using CDI?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to have a look at the [delta-spike exception control](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/core.html#ExceptionControl) mechanism in the core module. It provides you with a set of CDI artifacts to decouple the handling of exceptions from the component throwing them. This is the closest thing I can think of, to what you want to achieve.